# How to inspect elements like Firebug does it for Titanium applications?

Tags: android, firebug, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Is there any way to inspect HTML elements and their associated CSS rules of mobile applications developed using Titanium in same way like Firebug does in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

We've successfully used http://revealapp.com/ before for iOS

Comment: thanks for the answer Phil. Is there any similar elements inspector for android ?